# C++ Client/Server Chat App - Scanning Input from Ubuntu command window

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I am trying to take a partial input from my Ubuntu execution statement for a C++ program and set it as a variable in another program. For example, if I compiled my program and executed as such:

First, Window 1 (Server):

```
$ g++ server.cpp -pthread -o server
$ ./server
```

Then, Window 2 (Client):

```
$ g++ client.cpp -pthread -o client.out
$ ./client.out 4 5006 3002
```

How could I grab the 4, etc. from my input on the client side and set as variables int ID = 4, int port1 = 5006 and int port2 = 3002 (preferrably with code from the C++ program I compile) in my already executing server program? I'm assuming the code to do this would be put in my server C++ program?

The issue I'm having is how could I get the server to read this in as I'm executing the client connection?

Answer (score 0):

> How could I grab the 4, etc. from my input on the client side and set
>   as variables int ID = 4, int port1 = 5006 and int port2 = 3002
>   (preferrably with code from the C++ program I compile) in my already
>   executing server program? I'm assuming the code to do this would be
>   put in my server C++ program?

The only proper way to do it would be to have your client program send those values to the server as data (e.g. by connecting to the server via TCP and sending the values over the TCP connection; then the server program, upon receiving the bytes of data, would use them to set its variables as appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple TCP/UDP socket programming for doing so.

Take a look here 
This simple way can solve your purpose
Just send the command line args or take user input and then send

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/